# Angular&CSS: How to handle different designs for various data?

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular app that displaying data from search.

The data is nested `json` that contain an entry and two main fields.
let's call them field A and field B.
The result can be with a multiple entries (multiple resultContainer's with A's & B's)

I'm using `CSS` grid since it's my best option to set the display.

I made the design for the default possibility A & B and their child's.

```
<div class="resultContainer">
    <div class="A">
        <div class="data-x-f"></div>
        <div class="data-x-g"></div>
        <div class="data-x-e"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="B">
        <div class="data-x-t"></div>
        <div class="data-x-z"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.resultContainer {
    display: grid; /* the default should be just with this rule  */
}

.just-one-elemnt {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;  /* Should be just if 'B' has one child */
}
```

**The problem is:** I need to set a different `css` rule if field B has just one child.

So, the resultContainer rules should be with: `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%`

I tried to create a function to verify from the `json` how much data etc. but it affect the other elements and make them all with or without the `css` rule.

Here's screen shots for demonstration (Sorry for the terrible design skills):
[image]

Reminder: The page should display multiple containers with the both data (with one child for b or/and with multiple)

Comment: If you use ngFor to loop the elements you can check the length of the array you loop from and set the css accordingly.

Comment: Hey, I know and I did something like this to verify but somehow it affect the other elements so I can't seperate the rules

Comment: Can you show what you did exactly?

Comment: something that check the json object:
`
  itHasProp(term: any): boolean {
    if (term.hasOwnProperty('info1')) {
        return true;
    }
    if (term.hasOwnProperty('info2')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }`